# Django Annotate, сумма временных интервалов

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Имеются две модели:

```
class JournalEntryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def total_flight_time_per_day(self):
        return self.annotate(total_flight_time_per_day=Epoch(Sum('elements__flight_time')))


class JournalEntryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return JournalEntryQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def total_flight_time_per_day(self):
        return self.get_queryset().total_flight_time_per_day()


class JournalEntry(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    objects = JournalEntryManager()


class JournalEntryElementManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(duration=Epoch(F('flight_time')))


class JournalEntryElement(models.Model):
    journal_entry = models.ForeignKey(
        JournalEntry,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='elements',
)
    flight_time = models.DurationField()

    objects = JournalEntryElementManager()
```

Пытаюсь по аналогии с total_flight_time_per_day реализовать анотацию для модели JournalEntry с подсчётом кумулятивной суммы для временных интервалов от начала года до даты которая хранится в объекте модели.
Получилось сделать с помощью метода в сериализаторе модели, но таким образом получается много запросов к БД соответствующее количеству экземпляров которые требуется анотировать.
 К сожалению не очень хорошо разбираюсь в window function, нужна помощь. Может быть есть возможность сделать это с помощью подзапросов (SubQuery)?.

**EDIT**
В виде sql это выглядит примерно так:

```
SELECT journalentry.id,
       journalentry.date,

       COALESCE(EXTRACT('epoch' from SUM(journalentryelement.flight_time)), 0) AS total_flight_time_per_day,

       (SELECT COALESCE(EXTRACT('epoch' from SUM(U1.flight_time)), 0) AS total_flight_time_per_year
        FROM journalentry U0
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN journalentryelement U1
                                    ON (U0."id" = U1.journal_entry_id)
        WHERE U0.date BETWEEN '2019-01-01'::date AND journalentry.date)

FROM journalentry
            LEFT OUTER JOIN journalentryelement
                            ON (journalentry.id = journalentryelement.journal_entry_id)
GROUP BY journalentry.id;
```

Можно ли средствами orm сделать вложенный запрос который возвращает total_flight_time_per_year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге получилось таким образом:

```
class JournalEntryManager(models.Manager):
    def total_time_per_period(self):
        return self.get_queryset().annotate(
            total_time_per_day=Coalesce(Epoch(Window(expression=Sum('elements__flight_time'), partition_by=['date'])),  Value(0)),
            total_time_per_year=Coalesce(Epoch(Window(expression=Sum('elements__flight_time'), order_by=F('date').asc())), Value(0))
        ).order_by('date').distinct('date')
```

Для подсчёта налета за день указываем partition_by. Если не указывать партицию, то партицией является весь запрос.
С подсчётом суммарного налёта есть нюанс если не задан order_by в окне, идет подсчет по всей партиции один раз, и результат пишется во все строки (одинаков для всех строк партиции). Если же order_by задан, то подсчет в каждой строке идет от начала партиции до этой строки.